# Beginning Haskell: Calling a simple function, matching a data structure

Tags: haskell

I am a little embarrassed to be asking such a banal question on here, but I am trying to follow the recent 'Beginning Haskell' book (Apress) as an introduction to Haskell, but the code does not work. I found the source code online, which was identical to my own, and that doesn't work either.

```
data Client = GovOrg     String
            | Company    String Integer Person String
            | Individual Person Bool
            deriving Show

data Person = Person String String Gender
            deriving Show

data Gender = Male | Female | Unknown
            deriving Show

clientName :: Client -> String
clientName (GovOrg name)                         = name
clientName (Company name _ _ _)                  = name
clientName (Individual (Person fName lName _) _) = fName ++ " " ++ lName
```

When I attempt to call the function with

> clientName (GovOrg "NASA")

It returns "NASA".
But when I try to call it with:

> clientName (Company "Virgin")

Or:

> clientName (Individual "Adam" "Smith") -- (or any other permutations of this function call)

The result is Type mismatch, and:

> Probable cause: `Company' is applied to too few arguments

As you might be able to tell, I have a difficult time with the syntax at this stage, but I'm sure I would have a better time of it if I could get it to work in the first place. Is there something wrong with how I call the function from the interpreter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are not passing up the entire data. Try this:

```
λ> clientName (Company "Virgin" 3 (Person "fname" "lname" Male) "hello")
"Virgin"
λ> clientName (Individual (Person "Adam" "Smith" Male) True)
"Adam Smith"
```

Both `Company` and `Individual` are data constructors and you can inspect their type also:

```
λ> :t Individual
Individual :: Person -> Bool -> Client
```

So, for Construcing `Individual` you should pass `Person` and `Bool` type to it. Something like this builds up a `Client` type:

```
λ> let a = Individual (Person "Adam" "Roy" Male) True
λ> :t a
a :: Client
```

Comment: Thank you! The author never clarified how to call these functions, and I guess I assumed that since the defined function was uninterested in the entire data, the function call shouldn't include it. Thanks again!.

Comment: @user3710884, the arguments all need to be applied whether or not the function actually inspects all (or any) of them. If you don't apply all of them, what you get will actually be a function waiting for you to apply the rest. Since the `clientName` function is expecting a `Client` and getting a function instead you get a type error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you try to make a `Company` with `Virgin` as its only parameter. The parameters you actually need for a `Company` are a String **and** an Integer **and** a Person **and** another String.

```
clientName (Company "Virgin" 123 (Person "Three" "Fx" Unknown) "someString")
```

will work.

Comment: This is clearly not what you meant. Strings are not functions.

Answer (score 0):

Both `Company` and `Individual` have data constructors that take more than 1 argument. Specifically `Company` also takes an `Integer`, a `Person` and a `String`; `Individual` also takes a `Bool`.

Not only that, but `Individual` takes a `Person` as first argument.

You should, for example, call:

```
clientName (Individual (Person "Adam" "Smith" Male) True)
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d35ae32defb14384)